# SQL: Is there a way to capture "once every 45 days"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

First time post, but I've stumbled across Stackoverflow for years.

A patient might get a particular lab test many many times in a span of a few months. However, to reduce duplication, I only want to capture these results once every 45 days.  So if a patient had a lab test today, I can ignore the next 45 days' worth of lab tests.  But if a patient gets a repeat lab test, say, on day 51, I want to reset the "clock" and ignore the next 45 days' worth of lab tests.

Here's generally what I'm trying to do:

```
PatientID    Date    DayNum    KeepThis?    DaysSinceLastKeptTest
    1      3/2/2020     0        Yes                 0
    1      3/5/2020     3                            3
    1      4/6/2020    35                           35
    1      4/10/2020   39                           39
    1      5/15/2020   74        Yes                 0 (more than 45 days since 3/2 test)
    1      5/25/2020   84                           10
    1      5/30/2020   89                           15
    1      6/6/2020    96                           22
    1      7/1/2020   121        Yes                 0 (more than 45 days since 5/15 test)
    1      7/4/2020   124                            3
    1      7/15/2020  135                           14
```

(in my final product, I don't necessarily need the DayNum, KeepThis, or DaysSinceLastKeptTest columns. I just need the 3 "Yes" rows.)

I'm trying to do this in SQL, but can't figure it out.  I've thought about temporary tables or subqueries, and I'm just learning about OVER/PARTITION BY as a possible way to tackle this.

I appreciate any help or ideas you may have. Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I added tsql right now for Microsoft SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a recursive CTE you can do it:

```
with cte_rn
as
(
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by patientId order by testdate ) as seq
    from patients
),
cte_recursive
as
(
    select *,cte_rn.testdate as usedTestDate,1 as toUse
    from cte_rn
    where seq=1
    union all
    select rn.patientid,rn.testdate,rn.seq,case when datediff(day ,r.usedTestDate,rn.testdate)>45 then rn.testdate else  r.usedTestDate end  as usedTestDate,case when datediff(day ,r.usedTestDate,rn.testdate)>45 then 1 else 0 end as toUse
    from cte_recursive r
    join cte_rn rn
        on r.seq = rn.seq-1


)

select *
from cte_recursive
```

Comment: This totally worked!!! Thank you soooo much!!! I've been struggling with this all night, and you answered it in like 15 minutes!!!  This would have taken me like 2 years to come up with this answer.